# Queue script redirection

Tags: php, store

Thank you for reading this question, i have a client with a store and ask me to do user queue, lets say...

For example on Hot Sale days, the store get slow with a lot of visitors, so he wants me to an script, if the store has 3000 unique visitors at same time, the visitor 3001 should wait until one visitor left the store, so when there is 2999 users and 1 free slot, redirect him to the store.

How can you do something like this?

Comment: seems like a great way to loose customers. No one is going to wait in your queue. you need to fix the site to accommodate the users. AWS autoscalling is one option here

Comment: not at all, we had for example here the stones show and people stay until their turn, so, this work, this is a client requeriment not mine, so i need to do it, if you have at least the logic and how to implement something like this you are welcome...i dont need the code...just the first step to go with this challenge...

Comment: how do you measure if people leave, i know i would. As to "client requirement" that's because they dont know any better,  as the 'professional' you need to advise them. I haven't considered the logic, as its illogical to even consider it when scaling to demand is so easy now.

Comment: its not my project, i just has this requeriment, as i said before, it is something being used here, it is normal and people accept it...they dont have enoght products to sell or people to support so many clients at the same time, it is not just a performance problem at all, it is a company problem...without the enoght structure to support all people...its not a problem as developer...

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is really weird, I'll try to give you some idea.

I would definitely not block users before they come to the site, I would let them all browse items and put them into the basket. And only when customer tries to pay / finish order, there would be a disabled button and message saying something like `please wait you are in queue`. Every order should have some status and you can easily count `in progress` orders unless the order is processed by staff. If count of `in progress` reaches some given number, you know what to do.